# Profile sections

Tags: profile

Making some progress with providing mailing users with the opportunity to update their details. We're using custom fields to track completed training (which, date and who trained them).

I've got the custom fields for the training (one entry with multiple fields, 3 per training)

I've got checksum UI working, and can generate the custom URL to point a user to a profile.

I've got a profile which contains address details and the training fields. However, the page presented to the user is just one long list. It would be nice to group the fields in the profile. I don't think there's an easy way to use one page (URL) with multiple profiles each with their own headers.

Google has so far proven unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are well on the way. The normal way to do this in civi is

- send your contacts an email using a checksum to a profile link (for Edit)
- this should mean the profile pre-fills with their existing info
- they should be able to add new info or update existing info unless that field is set to read only.
- you should be able to use Profile Field type Formatting to add some HTML to give your self subheadings etc
- if you want something more than that, eg collapsible sections then depending on CMS, in Drupal use Webforms, in WP use Caldera forms.

I doubt I answered your question directly but perhaps the 'formatting' field can help you

Comment: You're most helpful as it means I'm in the right direction. For some reason, the formatting doesn't show up at all when I add it. I'll look at it again in more detail. Thank you! I did see Caldera, and will look into that as collapsible/conditional fields would be great.